# Reflect changes to file that .vimrc sources

Tags: vim

Here is my set-up. There is a ~/.vimrc that sources several files.

I make changes to one of these. And I do :so ~/.vimrc, the changes in the underlying files are not reflected. I need to quit and restart vim.

Is there any way I can achieve this? Let me rephrase, knowing vim. How do I get the changes to reflect without restarting vim?

Answer (score 0):

try with this command by adding it to .vimrc

```
autocmd! bufwritepost .vimrc source %
```

[Source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_vimrc_with_auto_reload)

Comment: This will reflect any changes made to ~/.vimrc. But if I make any changes to a file sourced in ~/.vimrc, they are not reflected

Answer (score 0):

In vim use `:so %` so that the current file being edited is sourced.